# Realistic BOAT/SHIP movement and rotation (2d)

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine

I want to move my boat to the position where i clicked BUT with a realistic movement and rotation :

[image]

([http://i.imgur.com/Pk8DOYP.gif](https://i.imgur.com/Pk8DOYP.gif))

Here is my code (attached to my boat gameobject) :

Basically, when i click somewhere, it move the boat until it reach the point that i clicked in the first place (i simplified my code for you)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class BoatMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 targetPosition;

    private float speed = 10f;
    private bool isMoving;


    void Update(){

        if (!isMoving && Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {

            targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            isMoving = true;
        } 


        if (isMoving) {
            moveToPosition ();
        }
    }

    void  moveToPosition() {


        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, 0f), speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.x == targetPosition.x && transform.position.y == targetPosition.y) {
            isMoving = false;
        }

    }
}
```

After some research and tries, i didn't find a way to do what i want.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well then, the first thing you should do is only advance along the `transform.forward` of the ship. Rotate the ship so that it can approach its destination. (The exact algorithm for the rotation will be the hardest part of the problem to solve, if you're turning as you move.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare

```
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private float targetDistance;
```

Then at the start of your move, do :

```
    targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    targetDistance = Vector3.Distance(targetPosition, transform.position);
```

While moving call this : (in your update loop for example)

```
    turnSpeed = 0.062f * targetDistance;
    moveSpeed = 35f * targetDistance;

    //Important /!\ : you need to add Linear drag on your rigidbody or it will keep adding
    RigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 

    var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (transform.position - targetPosition, Vector3.forward);
    newRotation.x = 0f;
    newRotation.y = 0f;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
```

Finally, add a linear drag value to your rigidbody (1 would be ok).

Thanks to [maksymiuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4979159/maksymiuk) who helped me and took a lot of his time trying to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts to this problem, which should be kept completely separate from each other and at no time does the equation of one interfere with the equation of the other.

### The first is the forward movement of the ship, which can be achieved in two ways:

**If you are using a rigidbody**

```
void Propel()
{
    float speed = 150f;
    RigidBody rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    Transform transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime); // <--- I always forget if its better to use transform.forward or Vector3.forward. Try both
}
```

**If no rigidbody**

```
void Propel()
{
    float speed = 150f;
    Transform transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```

### Now the second would be the turning of the ship, which also can be achieved in two ways:

**With rigidbody**

```
IEnumerator TurnShip(Vector3 endAngle)
{
    float threshold = Single.Epsilon;
    float turnSpeed = 150f;
    RigidBody rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    while (Vecotr3.Angle(transform.forward, endAngle) > threshold)
    {
        rb.AddTorque(transform.up * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Without rigidbody**

```
IEnumerator TurnShip(Vector3 endAngle)
{
    float threshold = Single.Epsilon;
    float turnSpeed = 150f;
    float step = turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    while (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, endAngle) > threshold)
    {
        newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, endAngle, step);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Then of course, the IEnumerators are called like so:

```
StartCoroutine(TurnShip(new Vector3(12f, 1f, 23f));
```

**Couple things to note:**

1. This is pseudo code, i haven't tested any of it so just know that making it work is up to you, i'm only providing you with the correct path to follow.
2. All the variables in the beginnings of the methods are meant to be global variables, so declare them where you please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer, i'm gonna try to make it work and get back to you asap

Comment: Whatever i try (with or without Vector3), it keep telling me : "Static member `UnityEngine.Vector3.forward' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead", my code :    RigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z).forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: `forward` is a static field. To call `forward` you can only do it like this: `Vector3.forward`.

Comment: I just tried again without replacing "transform.forward" by my target Vector3, and i don't have any error, but the boat doesn't move and no axis is being changed, here is the code : `float speed = 150f;
  Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  Transform transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
  rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);` i of course disabled "is kinematic" and have a mass of 1

Comment: Make the speed 150000000 and see if there is a difference. It is probably just moving extremely slowly

Comment: I tried with 150000000 and even 1500000000000, but the coordinates in the Transform component do not change :s

Comment: And you are running this code every frame? Did you set the value through inspector, if it is global? (Inspector values don't update through code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132929/discussion-between-maksymiuk-and-owow).

Comment: TL;DR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576456/realistic-boat-ship-movement-and-rotation-2d/41649467#41649467

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Transform called target here, just replace it with the Vector from your mouse click.

```
public Transform target;

private void Update()
{

    transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
    float step = Time.deltaTime / Mathf.PI;
    Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);

}
```

The key to this is the [RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) function and calculating a new vector to look towards on each frame based on the current position.

If your boats have some kind of rotation speed stat then modify the float called step to suit. If they have a speed stat then modify the transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime with some multiplier.

I guess you'll want to put some conditions in as to when to stop the movement and rotation, perhaps using a coroutine.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's working !! but how can i only rotate the Z axis ? since i'm in 2D (with a top down view, like on my example) here's a GIF of what happens actually : http://i.imgur.com/EO37TVq.gif

Comment: Just manipulate Vector3 newDir e.g. Vector3 zRotOnly = new Vector3(0,0,newDir.y), or whatever axis orientation your game uses.

Comment: I see but when i do that, it will indeed change only the Z axis but for the "position" instead of "rotation" `Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0f);
  Vector3 zRotOnly = new Vector3 (0, 0, newDir.y);
  transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(zRotOnly);`